# Plain TeX macro to read a document in Pig Latin

Tags: plain-tex, fun, parsing

Say I have a file `eng.tex`:

```
\def\encounter (#1){Hello, #1!}
\encounter (World)
\bye
```

I convert it to Pig Latin and save it as `pig.tex`:

```
\efday\encounterway (#1){Ellohay, #1!}
\encounterway (Orldway)
\yebay
```

Is there a way (e.g. header you could insert) to make TeX parse `pig.tex` like it was written normally in `eng.tex`, macros and all? (I'm not very experienced with how TeX parses and don't know where to start.)

Comment: Is there e.g. an `unpig` script written in a more conventional language to demonstrate exactly what you would want changed?

Comment: In this simple example, one could start by `\let\efday\def\let\yebay\bye`. Macro names don't require changing, but the non-macro names do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **NO** since the transformation from English to Pig Latin is not 1-to-1 and hence not invertible. Consider the statement

> in pig latin nails and snail are the same

Which according to the [rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) for converting English to Pig Latin becomes

> inway igpay atinlay ailsnay andway ailsnay areway ethay amesay

which is also Pig Latin for

> in pig latin snail and nails are the same